# KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([34.62365962451697, 30.28671076822607, 35.84740876993872], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

This is my dataframe:

```
          x1         x2  y  x2_modified
0  34.623660  78.024693  0    99.294362
1  30.286711  43.894998  0   110.085855
2  35.847409  72.902198  0    96.249345
```

When i try to access the column `x1`, it does it perfectly:

```
>>> print(df.x1)
0    34.623660
1    30.286711
2    35.847409
Name: x1, dtype: float64
```

But when i try to plot it,

```
df.plot(x = df.x1, y = df.x2_modified)
```

It gives above error:

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([34.62366, 30.286710999999997, 35.847409000000006], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

I'm not getting the reason, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) only pass columns names:

```
df.plot(x = 'x1', y = 'x2_modified')
```

If want use [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) then you can pass `Series`:

```
plt.plot(df.x1, df.x2_modified)
```